# image not uploaded in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is form action or other thing

```
<?php
echo form_open_multipart("/Register/registerformModel",
                         array("name"=>"subform2","id"=>"subform2"));
?>
```

This is HTML File

```
<input name="userfile" id="userfile" type="file" class="input"/>
```

This is the function which is used to insert an image file into database

```
public function registerformModel()
{
    $this->load->model("common_model");
    $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('upload_url_path').'images/member/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['file_name'] = date('Ymd_his_').rand(10,99).rand(10,99).rand(10,99);
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';
    $config['max_filename'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['upload_data']['file_name'] = '';
        echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:#FF0000;">','</p>');                    
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $config['upload_path'].$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $config['quality'] = '100%';
        $config['width'] = 50;
        $config['height'] = 50;
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('image_library', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }

    $data['query'] = array(
            'image' => $data['upload_data']['file_name']
            );  

    $num = $this->common_model->insert('member',$data['query']);
    $msg = ($num > 0) ? $this->lang->line('added') : $this->lang->line('not_added');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);         
}
```

The query is running successfully but image is not inserted.

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is the value of $this->config->item('upload_url_path')? and Image not uploading or not resized?

Comment: $config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/mediaguns/28_oct-2013/';
$config['admin_base_url']= $config['base_url'].'admin/';
$config['admin_base_url_path']= $config['base_url'].'administrator/';
$config['base_path']= '/home2/mediagun/public_html/';
$config['upload_url']= $config['base_url'].'uploads/';
$config['upload_url_path']= '/home2/mediagun/public_html/uploads/';

Comment: Ok thats fine. Do you get any error in <p style="color:#FF0000;"></p>?

Comment: image not uploading.... empty query is running

Comment: no error is displayed.

Comment: first u simply check upload then check conditions but it must but correct path $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$config['upload_path'] = $this->config->item('upload_url_path').'images/member/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else
{
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you replace this line $this->upload->do_upload() to $this->upload->do_upload(**'userfile'**)

and if you want to save resize image to any folder then please write $config['new_image'] = "path to save resized image";

I have tried this code and its working fine for me.

```
      public function registerformModel(){
        $this->load->model("common_model");
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/test';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['file_name'] = date('Ymd_his_').rand(10,99).rand(10,99).rand(10,99);
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';
        $config['max_filename']  = '0';
        $config['remove_spaces']  = FALSE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $data['upload_data']['file_name'] = '';
            echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p style="color:#FF0000;">','</p>');                    
        }
        else
        { 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $config['upload_path'].$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $config['quality'] = '100%';
        $config['width'] = 50;
        $config['height'] = 50;
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library(**'image_lib'**, $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        }

        $data['query'] = array(
                'image' => $data['upload_data']['file_name']
                );  

        $num = $this->common_model->insert('member',$data['query']);
        $msg = ($num > 0) ? $this->lang->line('added') : $this->lang->line('not_added');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);         
        }
```

All The Best

Comment: No need to add the filename if the input name is `userfile`.

Comment: i am also try this code but result is remain same. no image is uploaded.

Comment: i am using this code to resize the image.
$config['new_image'] = $config['upload_path'].'thumbs/'.$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
but no solution